# Can you run PL/Python or PL/v8 code from the database itself?

Tags: postgresql, plpython, javascript

It it possible to run code that is stored in the database, on the database.

For example, I'd like a trigger to execute a function whose Javascript code is stored in the same database. (Normally, functions are defined in advance.)

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131867/129805

You can use "eval", e.g.

```
create or replace function my_function()
returns text language plv8 as $$
//  load module 'test' from the table js_modules
    var res = plv8.execute("select source from js_modules where name = 'test'");
    eval(res[0].source);
//  now the function test() is defined
    return test();
$$;

select my_function();

CREATE FUNCTION
  my_function   
----------------
 this is a test
(1 row)
```

https://rymc.io/blog/2016/a-deep-dive-into-plv8/